# Enlarging encyrpted partiton on a SD card

Tags: partitioning, resize, fdisk

I have installed Ubuntu few weeks ago to try Linux for the first time. I used the Acer Cloudbook 14 and the hard drive shows up as an memory card in Ubuntu. Recently, I was in the process of formating a SD card with three partitions on it. I started by deleting the partitions and wondered why I had multiple partitions on an SD card. Finding that strange, I stopped and closed the window thinking it canceled the process. My system worked fine until I rebooted.

The BIOS displayed a message saying it couldn't find a bootable OS. I was able to restore the partitions with testdisk and a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it.

```
NAME         FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT                                LABEL
sda                  29.3G                                           
└─sda1       vfat    29.3G /cdrom                                    UBUNTU 16_0
loop0        squashf  1.4G /rofs                                     
mmcblk0rpmb             4M                                           
mmcblk0boot0            4M                                           
mmcblk0boot1            4M                                           
mmcblk0              58.3G                                           
├─mmcblk0p1  vfat     512M /media/ubuntu/6D91-4DE6                   
├─mmcblk0p2  ext2     488M /media/ubuntu/6d67f0bf-4575-4233-bb2c-d2c 
└─mmcblk0p3  crypto_    2M
```

I can now see 1 encrypted partition and 2 other partitions. However, when I enter my passphrase and the system displays an error message:

> Unable to access “2.1 MB Encrypted”
>
> Error unlocking /dev/mmcblk0p3: Command-line `cryptsetup luksOpen
>   "/dev/mmcblk0p3" "luks-8a590c4f-4ce1-4682-81b8-873788889e96" ' exited
>   with non-zero exit status 1: Requested offset is beyond real size of
>   device /dev/mmcblk0p3.

With GPart, I can see that I have an unallocated partition of 57.27GB. I think this is where my data is.

I have followed the instruction on [ResizeEncryptedPartitions][1] but I had an error message after deleting the 2 partition and creating a new larger partition with fdisk.

I rebooted and now I don't see my 2MD encrypted partition anymore, and see instead a new larger, extended and unallocated partition.

I tried to run:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 crypt1
```

And got the error message: *Device /dev/mmcblk03 doesn't exist or access denied.*

Here's what I have now:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 58.3 GiB, 62545461248 bytes, 122159104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x55fc3a23

Device         Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *       2048   1050623   1048576  512M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      1050624   2050047    999424  488M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3      2050048 122159103 120109056 57.3G  5 Extended




Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 29.3 GiB, 31466323968 bytes, 61457664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x30e0162d

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 61457663 61455616 29.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Any idea of what I should do?

Thank you very much!

V.